# ruby - many instances - parallel processing

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, processing

I'm new to ruby, and I,m not sure why is my program not working as expected.
The problem is that I'm playing with reading certain website and I'm trying to read some info. The problem is that I don't know how to create many instances of the XsidVehicle class.
There is 200 objects I'm trying to read, if each instance waits until the previous finishes then reading the info will take at least 200 seconds. I would like to create many instances with different IDs that would read different pages at the same time.

```
require 'open-uri'

class XsidVehicle

  def VehicleID(id)
    @id  = id
    individual_source = open("https://www.motocykle.com/cars/id/#{id}")
    puts individual_source[individual_source.index(id),individual_source.index(id)+12]
  end

end

source = open('https://www.motocykle.pl/cars').read
newItem = source.index('lId=')
endOfThePage = source.index('</html>')
myNewSource = source[newItem.to_i,endOfThePage.to_i]

    for i in 0..199 do
      #puts "This is i: #{i}"

        iid = myNewSource[myNewSource.index('"')+1,20]
        iid = iid[0,iid.index('"').to_i]

        myNewSource = myNewSource[myNewSource.index('class=').to_i,myNewSource.length]
        myNewSource = myNewSource[myNewSource.index('listingId=').to_i,myNewSource.length]

        puts "iid #{i}: #{iid}"     #here i noticed that the class instance is created then it navigates to the website to read it, and then a new instance is created. But I want many instances to be created at the same time, so not to be restricted by ordered processing.
        vehicle = XsidVehicle.new
        vehicle.VehicleID(iid)


    end
```

Comment: Find another way.  motocykle.com isn't going to be happy when you hammer their server with 200 concurrent requests.  You can use threads to parallelize requests, but make sure you keep it to a reasonable number of concurrent requests.

Comment: This question should not be tagged with the processing tag, because it has nothing to do with the Processing language.